# Preact Signals returns to default value when changing input

Tags: preact

I'm just trying to get to grips with Preact Signals so maybe I'm doing something wrong but I'm trying to allow the user to update a value but whenever they do it just reverts back to the default value. If I log it, it does show the changed value but immediately reverts back. Am I missing something?

So in the case below the input for reps is initially 10. If the user changes it, it will log the new value as well as new computed value but immediately return back to 10.

Thanks in advance

```
import { signal, computed } from "@preact/signals";

export default function SetInput({ setNo }: { setNo: number }) {
  const state = signal({
    reps: 10,
    weight: 20,
  });

  const volume = computed(() => state.value.reps * state.value.weight);

  const onHandleChange = (event: any) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    state.value = { ...state.value, [name]: parseInt(value) };
    console.log(name, value, state.value.reps, volume.value);
  };

  return (
    <div class="flex flex-row gap-8 mx-auto">
      <div>
        <label
          html-for={`s${setNo}-reps`}
          class="block text-md text-gray-400 opacity-85 mb-2"
        >
          Reps
        </label>
        <input
          name="reps"
          type="number"
          id={`s${setNo}-reps`}
          value={state.value.reps}
          class="shadow appearance-none border w-24 rounded py-2 px-3 text-gray-700"
          onChange={onHandleChange}
        />
      </div>
      <div>
        <label
          html-for={`s${setNo}-weight`}
          class="block text-md text-gray-400 opacity-85 mb-2"
        >
          Weight
        </label>
        <input
          name="weight"
          type="number"
          id={`s${setNo}-weight`}
          value={state.value.weight}
          class="shadow appearance-none border w-24 rounded py-2 px-3 text-gray-700"
          onChange={onHandleChange}
        />
      </div>
      <div>
        <span
          html-for={`s${setNo}-reps`}
          class="block text-md text-gray-400 opacity-85 mb-2"
        >
          Volume
        </span>
        <span class="">{volume.value}</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `signal` or `computed` inside components -- on every render, these will reset. Use the hook-like versions instead: `useSignal` & `useComputed`. Exact same API, so you don't need to make any changes other than the imports & function names.

Alternatively, move the `signal` & `computed` outside of your component.

> When creating signals within a component, use the hook variant: useSignal(initialValue).

[Docs](https://preactjs.com/guide/v10/signals#signalinitialvalue)

Comment: I was literally just typing to say I discovered the same thing myself when you posted. 

I did initially change it to useSignal/useComputed although have now moved it to a global state as that was ultimately the goal, just wanted to start off with something small to get to grips.

Thank you.